# Antlr: "spaced token" lexer style for keywords - why?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm studying the collection of grammars for various languages

The [SQL Lite Lexer](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/sqlite/SQLiteLexer.g4) uses this "spaced letter" style for defining the SQL keywords in the lexer.

so, for example:

`CREATE: C R E A T E`

... and then a set of fragments at the bottom for each letter in the alphabet.

I would have probably done the style below:

`CREATE: 'CREATE'`

I was curious what the spaced style they have used means - I tried both styles in the antlr intellij plugin and when giving it a program text of `CREATE`, it yields the same parse tree in both cases. I was curious/interested if the style they use has some intrinsic advantage, or is just stylistic?

Comment: Scroll further down that grammar file, and you see the reason: case insensitivity.

Comment: Cool - thank you. if you want to make it and answer instead of a comment, I'd be happy to mark as the accepted response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grammar you link uses a fragment for each character. That way it can process the grammar in a case-insensitive way.

At the bottom of the grammar, you see fragments defined like:

```
fragment A: [aA];
fragment B: [bB];
fragment C: [cC];
...
```

In other words, when you `CREATE: C R E A T E`, those spaced letters are actually fragments, which translate to `CREATE: [cC] [rR] [eE] [aA] [tT] [eE]`

For more details, see [Case-Insensitive Lexing](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/case-insensitive-lexing.md) in the ANTLR documentation.